Facebook SDK: How can I check the permission was granted or not when using limited login on IOS?
I need to know if player granted facebook permissions for my game or not, But I can't find the way to do it with limited login mode on IOS.
I go through so many Facebook documents but I has no luck.(official doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/limited-login)
Anybody know about this problem?

Don't see a direct way to do that like the regular API offers with the "normal" login. But using the profile helper class you can request the info the user shared with your app - and for those fields, that the user did not grant permission for, you will get nil. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/limited-login/permissions/profile-helper

Thank you. But I don't know why in my case, the value of friendIDs is still empty array (not null) when player has not granted the permission yet.
